# SQLite database editor with support for HTML syntax highlight?

Tags: sqlite, ide, editor

I would need a convenient way to edit HTML data in an SQLite database, preferably with the ability to save it directly to the SQLite database without having to first edit the text it in an (HTML-capable) text editor and then copy-paste it to an SQLite editor.

Do any such tools exist (for Mac OSx)?